# Как группировать 3 значения в один?

Tags: javascript, linq, google-apps-script

У меня массив массивов, длина массива 17672, каждый массив содержит 7 элементов.
Выглядит так:

```
id|  product |  client  | reward | tariff  | Threshold
------------------------------------------------------
1 |  guitar  |  john    | 0.2    | 0.5     | 500
1 |  guitar  |  john    | 0.3    | 0.6     | 1000
1 |  guitar  |  john    | 0.4    | 0.7     | 2000
2 |  drums   |  ringo   | 0.2    | 0.5     | 
2 |  drums   |  ringo   | 0.3    | 0.6     | 
2 |  drums   |  ringo   | 0.7    | 0.8     | 
3 |  cello   |  george  | 0.1    | 0.2     | 500
3 |  cello   |  george  | 0.2    | 0.4     | 800
3 |  cello   |  george  | 0.4    | 0.6     | 3000
```

Здесь еще есть столбцы, но я их убрал с ними проблем нет.

Из такой таблицы я хочу получить следующий JSON

```
 [
    {
        "limit": {
            "max": "10000",
            "min": "2"
        },
        "thesholds": [
            {
                "reward": 0.25653,
                "tariff": 0.41186,
                "threshold": "500"
            },
            {
                "reward": 0.58445,
                "tariff": 0.31421,
                "threshold": "1000"
            },
            {
                "reward": 6.71413,
                "tariff": 0.2757,
                "threshold": "2000"
            }
        ],
        "client": "john",
        "product": "guitar"
    },
    {
        "limit": {
            "max": "100",
            "min": "2"
        },
        "thesholds": [],
        "product": "drums",
        "client": "ringo"
    }
]
```

Мой предыдущий код который забирает данные из двух разных данных, продукты и пороги. 
Продуктов сейчас 11514, а порогов 9237.
Но этот код работает очень долго. Больше 6 минут, что не очень хорошо.
Сейчас я объединил две таблицы в один по ключу, и получилось таблица в примере выше.

**Вопрос: как сгруппировать 3 строки в один, а столбец thresholds добавить в массив?**

Я подумал, если объедение таблицы в один быстрее будет преобразований в JSON и отдать клиенту

В тегах нет этих технологии, напишу здесь

linqjs - http://neue.cc/reference.htm

google fusion table - хранилище данных от гугла

```
      function getClientsProducts() {

          // indexes
          var prdInx = clientsProductsIndex(SHEET_ID, "clientsProducts");

          // Fusion Table query
          var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tables["clientsProducts"];
          var fClientsProducts = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
              hdrs: false
          }).rows;

          return Enumerable.From(ClientsProducts).Select(function(prd) {
                  return {
                      limit: {
                          max: prd[prdInx.limit.max],
                          min: prd[prdInx.limit.min]
                      },
                      threshold: getClientsProductsThreshold(prd[prdInx.id]),
                      client: prd[prdInx.client],
                      product: prd[prdInx.product]
                  }
              })
              .Take(2)
              .ToJSON(null, 4)

      }

      function getClientsProductsThreshold(id) {
          var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tables["clientsProductsThreshold"] + " WHERE id = '" + id + "' LIMIT 3";
          var rows = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
              hdrs: false
          }).rows;

          return Enumerable.From(rows).Select(function(row) {
              return {
                  reward: row[1],
                  tariff: row[2],
                  threshold: row[3]
              }
          }).ToArray()
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не стал ничего менять. Переделал запрос другим образом. Оказывается массивы гораздо трудозатраны чем объекты. Поэтому решение было сделать следующим образом.
Отказаться от google fusion table, и для начало сделать лукап обектов по следующему сценарию

1. Сделать лукап объект из таблицы clients
2. Сделать лукап объект для продуктов каждого клиента
3. Пройти по таблицам clients.producst и clients.thresholds, записать данные в лукапы clients/products по ключам
4. Собрать clients/products обратно в массивы

1 проход по каждой таблице
в сумме - 3 просмотра таблицы (поскольку таблиц всего 3)

**Результат. Обрабатывал более 6 минут в предыдущей версии, сейчас менее 7 секунд**
Плюс, я думаю тут надо еще кое что оптимизировать нужно.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID);
```

//values
  var stor = {
    clients:     ss.getSheetByName("clients").getDataRange().getValues().slice(1),
    products:   ss.getSheetByName("clientsProducts").getDataRange().getValues().slice(1),
    percents:   ss.getSheetByName("clientsProductsPercents").getDataRange().getValues().slice(1)
  }

// indexes
  var i = {
    clients: clientsIndex(SHEET_ID, "clients"),
    products: clientsProductsIndex(SHEET_ID, "clientsProducts"),
    percents: clientsProductsPercentsIndex(SHEET_ID, "clientsProductsPercents"),
  }

function mapClient(client){
    var key = client[i.clients.key];
    return {
                key: key,
                name: client[i.clients.name],
                },
                percent: {
                    reward: client[i.clients.percent.reward],
                    tariff: client[i.clients.percent.tariff]
                },
                products: {}
            }
    }

function reduceClient(clients, client){
     clients[client.key] = client;
    return clients
  }

var clients = Enumerable.From(stor.clients).Select(mapClient).ToArray().reduce(reduceClient, {});

function mapClientProducts(row){
    var client = row[i.products.key].split("-")[0];
    var product = row[i.products.key].split("-")[1];
    clients[client].products[product] = {
        limit: {
            max: row[i.products.limit.max],
            min: row[i.products.limit.min]
        },
        percents: {}
        product: product
    };
  }

Enumerable.From(stor.products).Select(mapClientsProducts).Count();

function mapClientsProductsPercents(row){
    var product = row[i.percents.key].split("-")[1];
    var client = row[i.percents.key].split("-")[0];
    clients[client].products[product].percents = {
            reward: row[i.percents.percent.reward],
            tariff: row[i.percents.percent.tariff],
            threshold: row[i.percents.percent.threshold]
        }
  }

Enumerable.From(stor.percents).Select(mapClientsProductsPercents).Count();

function mapProducts(client){
  var products =  Enumerable.From(client.Value.products).Select("$.Value").ToArray();
  client.Value.products = products;
  return client.Value;
}

var result = Enumerable.From(clients).Select(mapProducts).ToArray();

return JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
}

Comment: А зачем вам промежуточный `ToArray` между map и reduce?

Comment: А ну это чтобы функцию внутри параметра Select не писать. А то в кашу превращается. Читайте го как mapClients

Comment: Не знаю, как в js, а в .NET reduce одинаково работает что на материализованной, что на нематериализованной последовательности. Поэтому промежуточная материализация избыточна. // И из `Select` не получится сделать `ToArray`, т. к. селектор, передаваемый в `Select` работает на единичных элементах, а не на всей последовательности.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, тут название просто вообще не в тему. Переименовал